# Analytics using mongodb - millions of events per day

Tags: mongodb

We have a game that sends about 50 million events daily to our server (event has an action,date,value and userId).
We wish to perform analytics on these events. Will it be possible to insert 50 million rows each day to a mongodb and then to perform analytics on it? Should we use a single collection for that? Is mongodb the right choice for such thing?

Comment: 50 millions/day = 578 /sec, so yes, it is possible. Perform analytics?  No one knows what do you mean by analytics and therefore there is no answer to this question. The same answer is for 2 other questions. And one more time - ask detailed questions that shows your research and you will get detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just writing 50 million records to a database (MongoDB or any other) is the easy part, the hard part is structuring the data being written in a way that makes it easy to answer the questions (aka queries) you will be asking of it.

One thing that MongoDB lets you do very quickly is update counters in place, which makes it possible to pre-calculate some of the "analytics" that you know in advance you will need all the time.  An example of that might be "how many users did X every day" or "how many actions were done on particular day".   As each event comes in, you insert it into a collection but also increase appropriate counters based on day, action, user, etc.

Various other calculations can be made on the full collection using the aggregation framework.  It would allow you to aggregate large amounts of data including various filters, groupings, etc.

There is [a discussion of making just these sorts of queries](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/asya%2420user%2420actions%2420aggregate/mongodb-user/e4pFT4RqMeU/KxVB8TJfhNkJ) against MongoDB in a thread on the Google Group for MongoDB Users, I recommend that you take a look and see how close it matches your requirements.